# Mongo update array of nested dict in Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to update a data but I'm facing the issue because it's nested form

some fields are already present in the database I have fetched them and stored them in the DF variable

the existing data structure looks like this

```
{
   "created_by_id":122,
   "updated_by_id":123,
   "farm_area": [
        {
            "area_id": 1,
            "area_name": "Area 1",
            "area_acerage": 4,
            "zone_latest_id": 1,
            "zone_name": "test zone",
            "zone_acerage": 2,
            "area_zone":[
                         {
                               "zone_acerage":0.3
                         }
                        ]
            "device_info":[
                           {   "device_id":232,
                               "device_type":"sensor"
                           }
                          ]
                            
        },
        {
            "area_id": 2,
            "area_name": "Area 2",
            "area_acerage": 4,
            "area_structure_type": "polyhouse"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I am trying this existing data by sending new data which

```
{
   "created_by_id":122,
   "updated_by_id":123,
   "farm_area": [
        {
            "area_id": 1,
            "area_name": "Area 1",
            "area_acerage": 4,
            "zone_latest_id": 1,
            "zone_name": "test zone",
            "zone_acerage": 2,
            "area_zone":[
                         {
                               "zone_acerage":0.3
                         }
                        ]
            "device_info":[
                           {   "device_id":232,
                               "device_type":"sensor"
                           }
                          ]
                            
        },
        {
            "area_id": 2,
            "area_name": "Area 2",
            "area_acerage": 4,
            "area_structure_type": "polyhouse",
            "area_zone":[
                         {
                               "zone_acerage":0.3,
                                "zone_name":"Test Zone"
                         }
                        ]
            "device_info":[
                           {   "device_id":232,
                               "device_type":"sensor"
                           }
                          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But every time I run this command

```
collection.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(str(kwargs['pk']))}, {"$set": request.data}, upsert=True)
```

The data is getting replaced by the new one and due to this I'm losing some of my columns from the database
But I'm looking for the output
in which both of them are merged so that I wouldn't lose any column and the structure remains the same

I anyone can help I am using Django and MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to `update` it using [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

N.B.:  You can replace `"_id"` and new data programmatically.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
},
{
  "$set": {
    "farm_area.$[elem].area_zone": [
      {
        "zone_acerage": 0.3,
        "zone_name": "Test Zone"
      }
    ],
    "farm_area.$[elem].device_info": [
      {
        "device_id": 232,
        "device_type": "sensor"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.area_id": 2
    }
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XAorZ29YgH5).

Comment: but every time the requested data is different it's not necessary that the device will be there every time or zone de details will be there every time then how would I make this update with ever condition.

Comment: @AdarshSrivastav  How do you determine what needs to be updated? ... or that any update is actually necessary?